# Json to Parquet Conversion

Tags: hadoop

Any one worked on JSON to Parquet Conversion, if so can you please let me know the steps.
I Have unload the data from MongoDB using the mongo export utility, this is in JSON format which needs to be converted to Parquet.

Comment: You can use Hive Queries for it provided you have Hive table on top of your JSON data. Can you be more specific about your needs ?

Comment: Have you read http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files ??